# Browser does not set focus on generated input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i try to create a editable table. For some reason i could not set a focus on my generated input. I wrote a small version for you for better understanding.

For some reason this code works in Chrome but not in Firefox. If the code becomes more complicated it does not work in chrome either. Any ideas how i could get a focus on my input?

Html:

```
<article>
  <div>value1</div>
  <div>value2</div>
  <div>value3</div>
  <div>value4</div>
</article>
```

css:

```
div {
    width: 200px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid green;
  }
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var currentTarget = false;
    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
      switch(e.keyCode) { 
        case 9:
        if(currentTarget != false) {
          save();
          moveRight();
          edit(currentTarget);
        }
        break;
      }
    });
    $("div").dblclick(function() {
        if(currentTarget != false) {
            save();
        }
      edit($(this));
      currentTarget = $(this);
    });
    function moveRight() {
      currentTarget = currentTarget.next();
    }
    function edit(target) {
        var text = target.text();
        target.html('<input type="text" id="changeEdit" value="'+text+'" autofocus />');
    }
    function save() {
      currentTarget.html($("#changeEdit").val());
    }
  });
```

Jsfiddle link: [click me](http://jsfiddle.net/uzvajzcw/)

**EDIT**

Solution:
Adeneo showed a better form of adding an input element. But the currect answer was made by zgood in the comments.

To prevent TAB for doing what it should do you have to use following function:

```
e.preventDefault();
```

Thanks a lot to everyone!

Comment: When do you want to set focus? On load? On double-click? on save, edit, move?

Comment: when i press tab and adding a new input into my next div.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drop `autofocus` and create a proper element with `$('<input />')` and once it's appended to the DOM, use `focus()`.

`autofocus` is known to be unreliable when used on elements appended later in the DOM, as it's only supposed to work for focusing an element on pageload etc.

```
function edit(target) {
    var input = $('<input />', {
        type  : 'text',
        id    : 'changeEdit',
        value : target.text()
    });

    target.html( input );
    input.focus();
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/or8k7guy/)

Comment: edit is not a correct type. my bad! i just tried ure solution in my fiddle. and now it does not work in any browser. try it yourself [link](http://jsfiddle.net/avb1ch22/1/)

Comment: @PabloChristiano you need to add the jQuery library to your fiddle

Comment: @PabloChristiano because your are using TAB to jump between fields you should also add a `e.preventDefault()` before your `save()` in your keydown event. Or else the TAB will do what its suppose to do and jump to the next visible input. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9fq50hs7/1/)

Comment: @zgood Thanks a lot! this was the function i was looking for! I would like to share a beer with you!